# find string at array index? Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, indexing

I have this string array:

```
String[] directionsList = {"north", "south", "east", "west"};
```

and I want to find the string at index i (i is a random variable determined in the method).
I have this:

```
String myDirection = directionsList.valueOf(i);  # I have no idea if this is even
                                                 # close to correct
```

So say i = 2, I want to return "east". Is there any built-in Java method to do this, or do I have to use a loop? Thanks.

Comment: `String myDirection = directionList[i]` ? Just make sure that `0 <= i < directionList.length`. Also you should read this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
String myDirection = directionsList[i];
```

Comment: nevermind, it's working now. what i have is i = random.nextInt(4) where random is a Random object. thanks for your help!